# Does Linux have support for network interfaces over an AT-Command serial modem?

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, modem

I've got a [Telit GM862-GPS module](http://www.telit.com/en/products.php?p_id=3&p_ac=show&p=7), which is a GPRS modem with a serial interface and uses the standard Hayes AT command set (with some extensions). What I'd like to do is to be able to connect this up to a Linux device so that existing software (such as wget, ftp etc) can connect to the internet through it. In my limited Linux experience, I would imagine that this would require the modem to be configured as a regular network interface device, but I could be wrong.

Is this something that is supported in the Linux kernel/are there existing drivers to do this?

Comment: Actually it probably uses the ETSI GSM 07.07 standard command set. http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/.../gsmts_0707v050000p.pdf

Comment: @Keith: The link seems to be broken. Could you update it, please?

Comment: Oh sorry, it got truncated. This should work. http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/07/0707/05.00.00_60/gsmts_0707v050000p.pdf

Comment: BTW, you don't need special kernel support for serial devices. It's already there. In fact there is support for speeds higher than 115200. See the setserial command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what you say (serial interface, AT command set), I think it would behave like a dial-up modem. Thus you could use something like `wvdial` or `ppp` to connect using it.

Also, [this repo on GitHub](https://github.com/kzar/telit-862-python-tools) looks relevant:

> This repository serves to group together a bunch of scripts I've been writing to assist in the development process with the Telit 862GPS. They are all designed for Linux with the exception of the bulkdownload script which is for Windows.

Comment: ppp isn't just for dial-up modems. For example, DSL often uses it. So can T1s, etc. And some VPNs. But yeah, ppp sounds like the right answer.

Comment: @derobert Interesting; I didn't know about that.

Comment: @Renan Thanks! After playing around a bit, I've managed to successfully use wvdial to connect my PC to the internet via the GM862-GPS.

Comment: @Renan I want to use ppp. I know the APN, username & pwd for my service provider. But, there is no dial-up number. Is there a way to use ppp with only the APN details?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to turn a serial port into a network interface, that is exactly what PPP (`pppd`) was designed to do.  It'll work over anything that looks like a serial port to Linux.  `pppd` supports sending out "chat text" which contains the necessary AT commands to setup and teardown the call.  You'll probably want to make your own chat script for this device.

Instead of `/dev/ttyUSB0` or whatever you see in examples, use the `/dev/{name}` of the serial interface that is exposed by your GPRS module.