# Controlling ppp's chat buffering

Tags: linux, tty, ppp

I looked at the ppp chat source and it uses `putchar` to write to the device.  When PPP is run over a line discipline like `n_gsm`, which multiplexes a tty via the GSM 07.10 protocol, a lot of extra data is created on the link.

Can I use `stty` or some other feature to glob data together?  For example, if the chat script has *AT\n*, the following may be sent to the serial port (with `n_gsm`),

```
f9 07 ef 03 41 d4 f9  ....A..
f9 07 ef 03 54 d4 f9  ....T..
f9 07 ef 03 0d d4 f9  .......
```

The extra characters are the `n_gsm` framing to a particular virtual serial port.  I would prefer,

```
f9 07 ef 07 41 54 0d xx f9  ....AT...
```

Reducing the traffic from 21 characters to 9 (and I haven't included acknowledgements).  The [AT GPRS question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48525/does-linux-have-support-for-network-interfaces-over-an-at-command-serial-modem) has some information related to this question.

What I am asking could also be achieve by altering ppp's `chat` to use `strchr('\')` and using `write()` instead of `putchar`.  I am hoping there is some `stty` command turn on a [Nagle like algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) for a TTY.

[**07.10 standard**](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/07_series/07.10/0710-720.zip)

[**n_gsm docs**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/serial/n_gsm.txt)